# Write a function to find the family tree of a tweet

Tags: python, dataframe, recursion, twitter, family-tree

I have a dataframe in Python, listing a bunch of tweets with their id, created time and the tweet id each  one has interacted with. e.g. `006` to `004`, `002` quoted `999` (`999` is an old tweet, not listed here). The table is sorted based on the created time.

```
+----------+---------------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+
| tweet_id |     created_at      | reply_to_id | retweeted_id | quoted_id |
+----------+---------------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+
|      001 | 2020-02-24 15:51:17 | nan         | 000          | nan       |
|      002 | 2020-02-24 15:52:17 | nan         | nan          | nan       |
|      003 | 2020-02-24 15:53:17 | nan         | nan          | 999       |
|      004 | 2020-02-24 15:54:17 | 001         | nan          | nan       |
|      005 | 2020-02-24 15:55:17 | nan         | nan          | nan       |
|      006 | 2020-02-24 15:56:17 | nan         | 004          | 003       |
|      007 | 2020-02-24 15:57:17 | nan         | nan          | 003       |
|      008 | 2020-02-24 15:58:17 | nan         | nan          | 006       |
|      009 | 2020-02-24 15:59:17 | 006         | nan          | nan       |
|      010 | 2020-02-24 16:00:17 | nan         | 008          | nan       |
+----------+---------------------+-------------+--------------+-----------+
```

I am trying to write a function to find the interaction history of a single tweet. e.g. `010` retweeted `008`, `008` quoted `006`, `006` retweeted `004` and also quoted `003`, `004` replied to `001`, `003` quoted `999`. I would like this function to return a list of tweets that traces back `010`'s history.

In other words, I would like:

```
input: '010'
output: ['008', '006', '004', '003', '001', '999']
```

code to generate this toy dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.array(
        [['001','2020-02-24 15:51:17',np.nan,'000',np.nan],
        ['002','2020-02-24 15:52:17',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
        ['003','2020-02-24 15:53:17',np.nan,np.nan,'999'],
        ['004','2020-02-24 15:54:17',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
        ['005','2020-02-24 15:55:17',np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
        ['006','2020-02-24 15:56:17',np.nan,'004',np.nan],
        ['007','2020-02-24 15:57:17',np.nan,np.nan,'003'],
        ['008','2020-02-24 15:58:17',np.nan,np.nan,'006'],
        ['009','2020-02-24 15:59:17','006',np.nan,np.nan],
        ['010','2020-02-24 16:00:17',np.nan,'008',np.nan]]),
        columns = ['tweet_id', 'created_at', 'reply_to_id', 'retweeted_id', 'quoted_id'])
```

I guess it might involve some recursive search? I could only handle when there is only one type of interaction (if tweets can only reply to each other. Not sure how to handle when `006` interacted with 2 tweets and it kind of creates two branches. Hope to get some help from you guys!

Comment: You might want to look into the NetworkX library, as this is clearly a graph problem.

Comment: "How do I implement this application" is not a Stack Overflow issue.  Repeat the intro tour, especially the parts of focusing a question.  At the moment, you need to research how to build and traverse a tree structure or graph.